# Connecting remote server Neo4j GCE from local browser

Tags: neo4j, google-compute-engine

I have trouble connecting to remote Neo4j server at Google Compute engine instance from local browser.

After a bit of research at SO I have edited my file accordingly and part of my `neo4j.conf` file looks like this:

```
# The address at which this server can be reached by its clients. This may be the server's IP address or DNS name, or
    # it may be the address of a reverse proxy which sits in front of the server. This setting may be overridden for
    # individual connectors below.
    #dbms.connectors.default_advertised_address=localhost

    # You can also choose a specific advertised hostname or IP address, and
    # configure an advertised port for each connector, by setting their
    # individual advertised_address.

    # Bolt connector
    dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
    #dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
    dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

    # HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
    dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
    dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474

    # HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
    dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
    dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473

    # Number of Neo4j worker threads.
    #dbms.threads.worker_count=

    #*****************************************************************
    # SSL system configuration
    #*****************************************************************

    # Names of the SSL policies to be used for the respective components.

    # The legacy policy is a special policy which is not defined in
    # the policy configuration section, but rather derives from
    # dbms.directories.certificates and associated files
    # (by default: neo4j.key and neo4j.cert). Its use will be deprecated.

    # The policies to be used for connectors.
    # 
    # N.B: Note that a connector must be configured to support/require
    #      SSL/TLS for the policy to actually be utilized.
    #
```

When I connect to the Neo4j server from my local browser I get an error:

> neo4j-web.min.js:20 WebSocket connection to 'ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:7687/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

xx.xx.xx.xx is my external GCE IP.[image: netstat --listen in GCE shows all the ports listening 7473,7474,7687 related to neo4j]

**netstat --listen in GCE shows all the ports listening 7473,7474,7687 related to neo4j**

Comment: Make sure that you have opened the relevant ports of your application on [Google firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) . I would also check that there is not a firewall software in the VM (i.e. iptables) filtering the connections.  You can also run [“netstat --listen”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538208/how-to-check-opened-closed-port-on-my-computer) to  confirm the server is listening on the appropriate ports.

Comment: I have edited my question and added a screenshot depicting the related ports listening on my VM .

Comment: Were you able to check the [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) for those ports (7473,7474,7687)?, if you run the [nmap utility](https://nmap.org/) you should see those ports as "open"